# First time using pthreads in C, why is nothing returned from these ones?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

In the following code:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...

    pthread_t t1, t2;
    int sp1, sp2;

    sp1 = pthread_create( &t1, NULL, getScalarProduct, NULL);
    sp2 = pthread_create( &t2, NULL, getScalarProduct, NULL);
    pthread_join( t1, NULL);
    pthread_join( t2, NULL);

    printf("Seperate scalars: %d %d\n", sp1, sp2);
    finalScalarProd = sp1 + sp2;


    printf("Result: %d\n", finalScalarProd);

    return 0;
}
```

I've been unable to get anything back other than zero for the finalScalarProduct, and both sp1 and sp2 are zero also. I believe it's something to do with the NULL argument being passed in pthread_join. I don't really understand what this argument is for.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: The return of `pthread_create` is not the return of the thread function. The thread function might not even be executing yet by the time it returns. The return of `pthread_create` simply indicates success or failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because pthread_create [returns zero upon success](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_create.html).
The value is not the result of the main thread function, but the result of the thread creation (that might fail in some cases).

```
void * threadMainFunc(void * arg) {
    // modify arg like this
    int * ip = (int *)arg;
    *ip = 3; // this is the "return value"
    return NULL;
}

pthread_create( &t1, NULL, threadMainFunc, &sp1);
```

Comment: How can I get the return value from return(scalarProd) then?

Comment: You will need to pass a pointer to the variable in pthread_create (the `arg` param)

Comment: Struggling with pointer theory over here. Would you be able to show me the code to do it and explain it?

Comment: @BinyaminSharet, your function has UB, since it doesn't return anything (in the proper sense), you'd have to put a `return 0;` or similar at the end.